# install random module of Chicken Scheme

Tags: chicken-scheme

```
chicken-install random
```

returns following errors.

```
Server error:

Error: [Server] no such extension or version
"random"
#f
Server error:

Error: [Server] no such extension or version
"random"
#f
```

So How can I install the Random egg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no egg called "random". See the [egg index](https://eggs.call-cc.org/5/).

However, there is a [(chicken random)](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20random)) module that's included in the distribution (you don't need to install it). To use it, put `(import (chicken random))` in your code.

If that's not what you were looking for, perhaps the egg you wanted is [srfi-27](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/srfi-27) or [random-mtzig](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/random-mtzig)?